# Minimise a function of three variables over a range (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, variables

I want to minimise the maximum value the function `f(a,b,c)` takes over the range `l <= c <= u` for some lower and upper bounds `l` and `u` by changing the parameters `a` and `b`. I think I will need a double iteration but beyond that I have no idea how to begin.

I would greatly appreciate any of: an answer, help in phrasing this more clearly or information about where I can look to find the answer myself. I have tried to look elsewhere for an answer, but I am struggling to know what to search for.

EDIT: As an example, suppose `f(a,b,c)` is `abs(g(a,c)-b)`. I have tried to vary `a` so that `p(a) = max(g(a,c)) - min(g(a,c))` is minimised over `c` which would then easily allow me to compute what `b` should be, but the problem I am having is that `g` is not necessarily an easy to work with function.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If yes, put your code here (whatever it is even with problems) so that others can help you modify the code to get your desired answer.

Comment: Ah, upon second read it appears you need [fminimax](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminimax.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fminsearch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) and add a large negative value to out-of-bound solutions:

```
% Your input
f = @(a,b,c) (a-2).^2+(b.^2-9)^2+sin(2*pi*c).^2;
u = 0.7;
l = -0.01;
% function to optimize
f2 = @(a) abs(f(a(1),a(2),a(3))+1e15*(a(3)>u|a(3)<l));
% Find a minima
fminsearch(f2,[1.6 1 0.2])
```

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis It's the DIY way =P

Comment: It's also more or less what my function does :) But your answer doesn't need an extra download, so suffices for this case.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what is happening there @Laure. Is there a mistake in the signs as you seem to be adding a positive value to out of bound solutions? Also, what does the '.' after (a-2) (among other places) do? However the main thing confusing me is that this seems to find the minimum value of `f` rather than minimise the maximum value it takes. For example, if we consider the function `h(x)=abs(a+b), 0<=b<=10` then `a=0,b=0` minimises h(x) but `a=5`minimises the maximal value it can take. Have I misunderstood what this code does? Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the optimization toolbox, use `fmincon`:

```
X = fmincon(@(X) max(g(X(1),X(3))) - min(g(X(1),X(3))),... % the "cost function", i.e., what you want to minimize
            [0 0 1],...                                    % an initial guess for [a b c]
            [],[], [],[],...                               % (irrelevant for your problem)
            [-inf -inf 1], [+inf +inf u]);                 % lower and upper bounds for [a b c]
```

If you don't have the optimization toolbox, you can use my `fminsearch` wrapper [`minimize`](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24298-minimize) in exactly the same way. `minimize` uses `fminsearch` (which is included in standard MATLAB), but `fminsearch` cannot handle constraints, and `minimize` can.

What's more, that "initial estimate" can be hard to come by. You can do a simple grid search (as you suggested), but that tends to be tedious and slow, especially for larger problems. `minimize` can run without an initial estimate, in which case it will try an optimization a bunch of times for a bunch of random initial values within the bound constraints, and return the best one.